# undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000106db51f8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Anyone know how to get around this? On OSX, trying to get RSpec running with Rails 3.0.7. Full details at:
https://gist.github.com/1017044

```
  it "renders buttons_widgets partial" do
    get :buttons_widgets
    response.should render_template("buttons_widgets")
  end


→ rspec tools_model_spec.rb
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/bundler/gems/rspec-core-bea2366c817e/lib/rspec/core/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant STRING
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/bundler/gems/rspec-core-bea2366c817e/lib/rspec/core/metadata.rb:48: warning: already initialized constant RESERVED_KEYS
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/bundler/gems/rspec-core-bea2366c817e/lib/rspec/core/pending.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_MESSAGE
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/bundler/gems/rspec-core-bea2366c817e/lib/rspec/core/world.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant PROC_HEX_NUMBER
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/bundler/gems/rspec-core-bea2366c817e/lib/rspec/core/world.rb:7: warning: already initialized constant PROJECT_DIR
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/bundler/gems/rspec-core-bea2366c817e/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:43: warning: already initialized constant CONDITIONAL_FILTERS
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/bundler/gems/rspec-core-bea2366c817e/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:48: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_BACKTRACE_PATTERNS
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/bundler/gems/rspec-core-bea2366c817e/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:13: warning: already initialized constant AT_EXIT_HOOK_BACKTRACE_LINE
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/bundler/gems/rspec-core-bea2366c817e/lib/rspec/core.rb:35: warning: already initialized constant SharedContext
Run filtered excluding {:if=>#<Proc:/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:43>, :unless=>#<Proc:/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:44>}
F

Failures:

  1) ToolsController renders buttons_widgets partial
     Failure/Error: get :buttons_widgets
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000106db51f8>
# ./tools_model_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: is there a `buttons_widgets` action in the controller?

Comment: yes, i do. it's complaining about the 'get' method call.

Comment: If you just upgraded to rspec 3.x and are now getting this error see @juankuquintana answer down below

Answer (score 136):

RSpec doesn't know that your spec is a controller spec, so your examples don't have access to a `get` method.

RSpec 2.x assumes that everything in the controllers directory is a controller spec.

This was changed in RSpec 3:

> #### File-type inference disabled by default
>
> Previously we automatically inferred spec type from a file location, this was a surprising behaviour for new users and undesirable for some veteran users so from RSpec 3 onwards this behaviour must be explicitly opted into with:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#file-type-inference-disabled

In the [rspec-rails README](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#controller-specs):

> Controller specs default to residing in the `spec/controllers folder`. Tagging any context with the metadata `:type => :controller` treats it's examples as controller specs.

An example of setting the controller context metadata for RSpec:

```
describe ToolsController, :type => :controller do
    # ...
end
```

Comment: i tried spec/controllers and spec/app/controllers nothing worked... but :type did :D

Comment: The same for me: ../controllers/controller_spec.rb did not work.
+1 for :type

Comment: Mine solution was to restart Spork :)

Comment: I put my require 'spec_helper' after other requires in my test and that really messed things up. This solution worked for me after I put my require 'spec_helper' first. +1

Comment: I added type: :controller and worked....but is strange! 

Do I have to add it to all controllers spec? 

They are already unders controllers folder

Comment: Thanks, Josh. Tweaked the name of the link to clarify. (Of course the controller specs are rails-specific.)

Answer (score 25):

If at all you are using 'spec/features', you may need to add the following to your 'spec_helper.rb'

```
config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :feature
```

Comment: When updating to Capybara 2, this may be the case.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. As @tmg said, I have just upgraded Capybara to 2.x

Answer (score 25):

In Rspec 3.x the spec type is not automatically inferred from a file location, and you must manually set it, add this to the spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

[Rspec upgrade](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#upgrade-note)

Comment: Spent a long time looking for this solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is the right answer if you have just upgraded to RSpec 3.

Comment: If you use the rails helper from RSpec 3, the spec type *will* be inferred based on the file location. So there is no need to change this as long as you `require 'rails_helper'` at the top of every spec file.

Comment: As Joost aluded to - make sure you have `require 'rails_helper'` -- not `require 'spec_helper'`

Comment: this is for rspec-rails

Answer (score 15):

I was able to fix this issue in my app by adding `require 'rspec/rails'` to my spec_helper file.

Answer (score 14):

For others looking into this. I was trying to track down a `undefined method 'get'` error. My issue was that I had the `get` in a `describe block` make sure your `get` is in an `it block`.

Comment: ugh I facepalmed so hard when I read this and it fixed my issue :/

Comment: @catsby 2x facepalmed. le' sigh.

Answer (score 5):

Solved by replacing the line 
`describe PagesController do` with 
`RSpec.describe PagesController, :type => :controller do`
in the **_spec.rb** file in spec folder.
 Also to prevent deprecation warning use `expect(response).to be_success` instead of `response should be_success`.
PS: Didn't have to add `require "rails_helper"`.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I forgot to add `require 'spec_helper'` to the top of my spec file or `--require spec_helper` to my .rspec file.

Answer (score 2):

this can happen under the following conditions:

1. your spec does not have  `:type => :controller` [`type: :controller` in newer Ruby]
2. your spec is not in the controllers folder or you not have set `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!`

Either #1 or #2 must be setup for your spec. Also, this can happen under this condition as well:

3. you have written a spec using the old-style `require 'spec_helper'` instead of using the newer `require 'rails_helper'`. You will note that `rails_helper` now includes `spec_helper` (to generate both see the [Rspec installation steps](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails))

cross referencing GH issue https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing/issues/36

Answer (score 2):

If you used `rspec` to generate the `.rspec` file, you should change the content from:

```
--require spec_helper
```

to:

```
--require rails_helper
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to specify `type: :request` for your spec. For example:

```
RSpec.describe "Widget management", :type => :request do

  it "creates a Widget and redirects to the Widget's page" do
    get "/widgets/new"
    expect(response).to render_template(:new)

    post "/widgets", :widget => {:name => "My Widget"}

    expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:widget))
    follow_redirect!

    expect(response).to render_template(:show)
    expect(response.body).to include("Widget was successfully created.")
  end

end
```

Example taken from here https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I added

```
gem 'rspec'
```

to my Gemfile in the rails project. It should be

```
gem 'rspec'
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

(or just rspec-rails). After

```
bundle install
```

re-create the spec directory with

```
rspec --init
```

and put your xxx_spec.rb file in the appropriate directory (won't work if it is in the spec directory). Beginners error but maybe this helps somebody ;) Here's the link that helped me:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/gettingstarted

Answer (score 0):

For Access request get,post,patch and delete, You can use both `request` and `controller` in  `:type`

I prefer `:request` type for API Rspec and simple `:controller` for controllers Rspec

Here For Request,

```
RSpec.describe ToolsController, type: 'request' do

   it "renders buttons_widgets partial" do
     get :buttons_widgets
     response.should render_template("buttons_widgets")
   end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Gemfile:

In ":Test" block, add

```
gem 'rspec'

gem 'rspec-rails'
```

In your Test file:

On top of the test file, you should also require 'rails-helper' library

**In the Test file, when you describe the controller, your should mention that the type of the class is "Controller" like this:

```
describe MyController, type: :controller do
```

**note: Don't forget to use 'Bundle install' after changing the GemFile**