# Undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1 displayed in Rspec Controllers

Tags: ruby, rspec, get, controllers

After running the following code from Rspec - Controllers, I get an error from the `get` method

```
it "assigns @MyItems" do
  my_item = mock(:mypay_items)
  my_item = mock( MyItem)
  MyItem.should_receive(:all).and_return(my)
  get 'index'
  assigns[:my_items].should eql(my_items)
  response.should be_success
end
```

It results in an error:

```
undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x34b6ae0>
```

Comment: Can you post the whole file for your controller spec?

Answer (score 6):

It would seem that you're not properly declaring your spec as a controller spec, which results in the HTTP request methods (`get`, `post`, etc.) not being available. Make sure that at the top of your spec, you have something like:

```
describe PostsController do
   ...
end
```

Replace `PostsController` with the name of your controller. If that doesn't work, add `:type => :controller`:

```
describe PostsController, :type => :controller do
   ...
end
```

See also this answer: [undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000106db51f8>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296235/undefined-method-get-for-rspeccoreexamplegroupnested-10x00000106db51f)

Answer (score 4):

If at all you are using 'spec/features', you may need to add the following to your 'spec_helper.rb'

```
config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :feature
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the solution that worked for me was to add require 'rspec/rails' to my spec_helper file. All my controllers were setup correctly and adding the :type => controller didn't help.

Comment: me too! don't know what is broken, but this was the only solution for me, with also `type: :controller`. maybe the Rails version? using RSpec 3.2.3 and Rails 4.1.1