# Getting undefined method get on a named route in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I keep getting this error that I just can't figure out:

```
Failure/Error: get :find_movies, {:id => @id_passed }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x0000000363f800>
```

For the following rspec test:

```
it 'should find the movie in the database by the passed id' do
        Movie.should_receive(:find).with(@id_passed).and_return(@movie_found)
        get :find_movies, {:id => @id_passed }
end
```

which uses the following route:

```
get '/movies/find/:id' => 'movies#find', :as => :find_movies
```

And my controller includes:

```
def find
  @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
  if @movie.director != ""
    @similar = Movie.where({:director => @movie.director}).all if @movie.director
  else
    flash[:warning] = "\'#{@movie.title}\' has no director info"
    redirect_to movies_path
  end
end
```

My friend pretty much wrote the exact same code and got it working.  Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working?  Many thanks!

Comment: can u paste result of rake routes cmd

Comment: Could you also paste the beginning of the rspec file please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rspec` may not be seem to take that your spec is a controller spec.You can add a `type` to your describe like this

```
describe YourController, :type => :controller do
...
end
```

Another fix may be by adding `require 'rspec/rails'` to spec_helper

If you are using 'spec/features', you may need to add the following to your 'spec_helper.rb'

```
config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :feature
```

See this answer for more : [undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000106db51f8>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296235/undefined-method-get-for-rspeccoreexamplegroupnested-10x00000106db51f)