# Rspec not loading support files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this file:

```
# support/auth_macros.rb
module AuthMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @logged_in_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: "logged_in")
      sign_in @logged_in_user
    end
  end

  def logout_user
    before(:each) do
      sign_out @logged_in_user
    end
  end
end
```

In my `spec_helper` file, I have this line:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

Yet when I run rspec, I get errors like:

```
undefined local variable or method `login_user' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::PostsController::POSTCreate::WhenSignedIn:Class
```

The relevant function is located in `support/auth_macros`, which I assume would be picked up by the `require` statement in my `spec_helper`.

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: is it `support/auth_macros.rb` - extension is important

Comment: Yep, it's an `rb` file.

Comment: Could you show us this file as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have required the file, but the method is wrapped inside a module. You need to either remove the wrapping module or include it within your group test.

Update:

To be 100% specific: `require` loads the file and do nothing else. After file is required, the module has been created, but it is not included. You need to include it with: `include AuthMacros`

Comment: In my group test, I `require 'spec_helper'`, which in turn has required the module. Unfortunately, even when I directly require 'support/auth_macros'`, this error persists.

Comment: @timothycommoner - Updated question so it is more clear.

Comment: Ah, I see now. It looks like it had been extended through the config: `config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller`. I went ahead and removed that line and then took the functions out of their module. The error I was experiencing left, but new errors appeared within my controller specs, such as `undefined method 'get'` and `undefined method 'post'`. By default, the controller spec has access these methods, right? So perhaps there's a deeper problem here. Any ideas, or should I open a new question?

Comment: Looks like the problem is that rspec isn't identifying these specs as controller specs, so it isn't loading the necessary functions--including the ControllerMacros, which in turn load other macros such as the AuthMacros. Anyone else who experiences this problem can find more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296235/undefined-method-get-for-rspeccoreexamplegroupnested-10x00000106db51f).

Comment: In particular, upgrading to Rspec 3.0 caused the problem. It no longer infers the spec type from the path, though you can override this behavior in the `spec_helper` with: `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!`

Answer (score 1):

If your file relative path like `support/auth_macros.rb` and you wanna load it on `selenium_helper.rb` file, you need to do both step bellow:

1. Call `require` to load the file: `require 'support/auth_macros'`
2. And `include` it using: `include AuthMacros`

Hope it help.