# RSpec: undefined method `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x00000103bc6020> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller

I am writing some tests for my Rails controller, and I am using RSpec 3.0.2

After getting this error, when I try to simulate a `POST` call to a route:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `post' for #   <RSpec::ExampleGroups::WebApplicationsController::ProcessPayment:0x00000106214ce0>
```

I then read t[his SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296235/undefined-method-get-for-rspeccoreexamplegroupnested-10x00000106db51f) and I added the following line to my `spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configuration.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
```

Which gives me the following error when I run `rspec spec`:

```
code/fsa/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x0000010420e040> (NoMethodError)
```

I am not really sure what is going on.

Comment: Does this work if you tag the example with `type: controller`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was happening due to the fact that I was using `gem 'rspec'` instead of `gem rspec-rails`