# NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, request

First of all, this is my first experience with ruby. At this moment, I'm creating tests for the a Controller called Exporter in my application. The method of the Controller I want to test is this:

```
def export_as_json(equipments)
    equipments_json = []
    equipments.each {|equipment|
        equipment_json = {
            :id => equipment.id,
            :title => equipment.title,
            :description => equipment.description,
            :category => equipment.category_id
        }
        equipments_json << equipment_json
    }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json =>equipments_json }
    end
end
```

So, when I try to create a request for this method using this:

```
RSpec.describe ExporterController, type: :controller do
  get '/equipments/all', headers: { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json' }, format: :json
  expect(response.response).to eq(200)
end
```

inside the `exporter_controller_test.rb` file I'm receiving this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::ExporterController:Class
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296235/undefined-method-get-for-rspeccoreexamplegroupnested-10x00000106db51f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the problems pretty much every one runs into at least once ;)

Step 1: Read the error message very carefully

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'get' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::ExporterController:Class
```

Step 2: Remember the wording `NoMethodError: undefined method get for RSpec::ExampleGroups::XXX:Class`

Step 3: Solve it by making it an actual example

```
RSpec.describe ExporterController, "#index", type: :controller do
  it "should respond with status: 200" do
    get '/equipments/all', headers: { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json' }, format: :json
    expect(response.response).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

You were simply missing the `it` block.

Comment: But when I use the `it` block says: 

`ExporterControllerTest#test_test_saving_one_equipment_and_export_with_JSON:
NoMethodError: undefined method each' for nil:NilClass` 

Also, I should use the `rspec` or `rspec-rails`? Should I use the `config` or RSpec too?

Comment: You should use rspec-rails, since it creates a very useful rails_helper file for you.
Also that error message is very strange, without a stacktrace it is very hard to tell what it means.

Comment: I run the `rspec --init` now. What I should do now?

Comment: I think you can just go by the rspec-rails documentation, even though you already ran rspec --init. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Comment: Where I should use this 

`RSpec.configure do |config| config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location! end`

?

Comment: @olegario There is an RSpec.configure block in the spec file, add it in there, or maybe it is already in there but commented out.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an answer to your question. But, since you mentioned that you're new to ruby, I thought I would point out that your code could be simplified and prettified a bit.

First, you don't need to do `equipments_json = []` and then `equipments.each`. That's what `map` is for:

```
def export_as_json(equipments)
  equipments_json = equipments.map{|equipment| {
      :id => equipment.id,
      :title => equipment.title,
      :description => equipment.description,
      :category => equipment.category_id
    }
  }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json =>equipments_json }
  end
end
```

Now, that `hash` you're putting into `equipments_json` is just a subset of `equipment`'s attributes. So, use `slice` there to get the attributes you want:

```
def export_as_json(equipments)
  equipments_json = equipments.map{|equipment| equipment.attributes.slice('id','title','description','category_id')}

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json =>equipments_json }
  end
end
```

That `map` line is still a little long, so, maybe put it into a `do` block (like you had with `each`):

```
def export_as_json(equipments)
  equipments_json = equipments.map do |equipment| 
    equipment.attributes.slice('id','title','description','category_id')
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json =>equipments_json }
  end
end
```

And personally, I like using symbols instead of strings as my keys, so use `with_indifferent_access` so that you can use symbols:

```
def export_as_json(equipments)
  equipments_json = equipments.map do |equipment| 
    equipment.attributes.with_indifferent_access.slice(:id, :title, :description, :category_id)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json =>equipments_json }
  end
end
```

That line got a little to long again, so I think I would go ahead and wrap it:

```
def export_as_json(equipments)
  equipments_json = equipments.map do |equipment| 
    equipment.
      attributes.
      with_indifferent_access.
      slice(:id, :title, :description, :category_id)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json =>equipments_json }
  end
end
```

Now, there are some different ways to get those attributes you want (e.g., modifying `to_json`). But, this will get the job done.

Hope that helps and good luck!

PS: I just noticed in your original hash, you're doing:

```
:category => equipment.category_id
```

if that's not a typo and you really want `category` instead of `category_id`, then you could do something like:

```
def export_as_json(equipments)
  equipments_json = equipments.map do |equipment| 
    equipment.
      attributes.
      with_indifferent_access.
      slice(:id, :title, :description).
      merge!(category: equipment.category_id)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json =>equipments_json }
  end
end
```

Also, the convention for hashes is to do `title: equipment.title`. `:title => equipment.title` absolutely works, but is not the current convention. [This](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) is a style guide for ruby, in case it helps.

Comment: Dude, you are a living legend.

Comment: Haha. Thanks, I think?